# Pulling files from client workstations

Tags: web-applications, web

I need to upload a file to my server without user interaction, file is generated while the user is offline and upload needs to happen when they become online. Users are aware that we will be running an alternative app to handle offline data collection.

I'm trying to stay away from installing any app to their workstations do the upload, I did write apps to do this in Java and .NET but I want to keep the whole thing as Web App.

Users in subject already using my web site when they get online.

Is there any way I can pull these files when they are on my web site? I am guessing I will have security issues if I try to open/read/upload files from a location on Workstation.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can pull these files when they are on my web site?

No. Web sites cannot make a browser upload an arbitrary file from the user's file system. That would be awful for security.

The user either has to manually select the file, or you need to have the software that performs the upload installed on the user's computer.

Comment: Can I see if the files are present in a certain folder? These are XML files, can I read the content then?

Comment: No. Directory listings can leak private information just as easily as the contents of files. No. XML files can contain private information just as easily as any other kind of file.

Comment: Any idea if it is possible to set cookies from an offline application to retreive from borwser later.